# c++ different objects with vector all contain same contents

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

In c++, I have an object, containing a vector which contains pointers to objects of another class, but when I add the specific pointers to the vector, all the vectors of the objects contain the same pointers which were assigned to just one of the objects.

To be more specific; I have a class City, which contains a vector which contains pointers to objects of the class Road. Specific roads need to be assigned to different Cities. I add these specific pointers to each city, but at the end, each and every vector seems to contain the pointers which were assigned to just one city.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class City;

class Road;

class City{
    private:
        string name;
        vector<Road*> cons;
        City* parent = nullptr;
        bool visited = false;

    public:
        City(string naam);
        string getName();
        void addPtr(Road* conn);
        Road* getPtr(int n);

        void setBool(bool B);
        bool getBool();
        void setParent(City* C);
        City* getParent();

        int consSize();
        vector<Road*> getCons();
        void print();
};

class Road{ 
    private:
        int dist = 0;
        pair<City*, City*> cons;

    public:
        Road(int dis, City* city1, City* city2);
        pair<City*, City*> getPair();
        int getDist();

        void print();
};

City::City(string naam){
    name = naam;
}

vector<Road*> City::getCons(){
    return cons;                       
}

void City::addPtr(Road* conn){
    cons.push_back(conn);
}

Road::Road(int dis, City* city1, City* city2){
    dist = dis;
    cons = {city1, city2};
}

main(){
//cities
City milan("Milan");
City bolzano("Bolzano");
City turin("Turin");
City verona("Verona");

//Roads
Road BM(86, &bolzano, &milan);
Road MT(48, &milan, &turin);
Road GT(18, &genoa, &turin);
Road GM(60, &genoa, &milan);
Road MV(42, &milan, &verona);

//connections
milan.addPtr(&BM);
milan.addPtr(&MT);
milan.addPtr(&GM);
milan.addPtr(&MV);

bolzano.addPtr(&BM);

turin.addPtr(&GT);
turin.addPtr(&MT);
}
```

Additional code can be provided (I've just include the function declarations to keep the code shorter), I checked other problems on here (and on other places, but I don't think I've seen something that seems similar to my problem or I'm just phrasing my question wrong.

Comment: provide the code for City::addPtr() as well as the definition for your constructor

Comment: I added that part to the code

Comment: show me the definition for your constructor for City

Comment: ok, you never initialize your vector of roads in the constructor of city. you should have City::City(string naam):name(naam),conn(vector<Road*>()){}

Comment: I did that but, I still have the same problem

Comment: What is the implementation of `vector<Road*> getCons();` you are returning newly created vector, but how exactly?

Comment: How do you implement your road constructor and what is your output, by the way?

Comment: @kamerunka I added that

Comment: @Bob__ I added that it

Comment: You declare `City` objects with local storage and then put the address into your `Road` objects. This is usually not a good thing as those pointers will not be valid when the `City` objects go out of scope (either don't use pointers at all, or use smart pointers / allocate with `new`).

Comment: @Bob__ genoa is added in the full version of the code, I just added a few to set the example

Comment: @crashmstr Could you explain me how precisely how I could do that? I'm very new to this and have yet much to learn

Comment: He's asking where are you declaring all that variables, in main()?

Comment: @Bob__ yeah, do you want me to put all the declarations in the post?

Comment: No, the problem is where are you allocating memory for your vectors.

Comment: @Bob__ Like I said before, I'm very new to this, I don't really understand what you mean :/

Comment: the //cities ... //connection part of your code is outside the function main() or inside another function? What is your output and do you get it?

Comment: @Bob__ It seems I forgot to copy paste my main function, yes, the cities, roads and connections are declared inside my main.

Comment: So they are local to main(). I imagine you are using them inside main() too. Again, why do you think that the pointers are the same for every city? How do you output the values?

Comment: How are you determining that all the vectors contain the same thing?

Comment: You should probably add the code that shows the problem that you are seeing. What is the output you get?

Comment: I applied @crashmstr sollution and that fixed it, still thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @Bob__ I had print fucntions for the Roads and Cities,

Comment: @villintehaspam The output I got were the names of the cities (or cities which had a road)

Comment: It is not unlikely that your problem resides in the code that does the output. The example in your question does not seem to show the problem.

Comment: @villintehaspam crashmstr's sollution fixed it for me, so the problem did not reside in my output functions, still thanks

Comment: The comment you chose as an answer is actually kind of bad advice. It is true that you need to be careful not to have dangling pointers and one solution is indeed to use shared_pointer, but just replacing normal pointers with smart pointers is not always the best thing to do. The key is to understand who the owner of the objects is and their lifetimes. It is perfectly acceptable to use normal pointers if you know that they do not go out of scope before the pointer itself. Also, "allocate with new" is very seldom the right thing to do, use make_unique or make_shared.

Comment: Since the code you posted in the question did not show the problem, I cannot say whether your output code is to blame or not. It could have been that you had a completely different example that did use incorrect pointers as well. Either way, glad your problem got fixed. You should probably ask @crashmstr to turn his/her comment into an answer and then accept that answer rather than to copy it into an answer yourself. That way, he/she gets the reputation.

Comment: Yes, I know, I already posted a comment (directed to him) saying his solution worked for me, but hence he didn't post it as an actual awnser, I did it myself, I'll check this question later to see if he added his awnser (and if he did I'll remove mine). Thanks for the extra information though!

Comment: And the code used to output the Roads/Cities were just simple functions which used cout to print the name of the citie(s)

Answer (score 0):

> You declare City objects with local storage and then put the address into your Road objects. This is usually not a good thing as those pointers will not be valid when the City objects go out of scope (either don't use pointers at all, or use smart pointers / allocate with new). – crashmstr

This fixed it for me